# How to run two instances of neo4j on the same machine using docker-compose

Tags: neo4j, docker-compose

Can i run two instances of neo4j on the same machine using docker-compose ? If i have one instance as per following settings, what should be port settings for the second one ? or any other necessary setting that i must do ?

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    neo4j:
        container_name: Neo4j_test
        image: neo4j:latest
        volumes:
            - ./neo4jdb/data/:/data/ 
            - ./neo4jdb/conf/:/conf/
            - ./neo4jdb/logs/:/logs/             
            - ./neo4jdb/plugins/:/plugins/   
            - ./neo4jdb/import/:/import/ 
        ports:
            - "7474:7474" 
            - "7687:7687"
        environment:
            - NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true 
            - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true 
            - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use_neo4j_config=true
            - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
            - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=512m
            - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=8G
            - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test
        networks: ['Neo4j']
        restart: unless-stopped

networks: {Neo4j: {}}
# use docker volume to persist data outside of a container.
volumes:
  Neo4j_data:
```

Here is `docker-compose.yml` of second container.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    neo4j:
        container_name: Neo4j_test2
        image: neo4j:latest
        volumes:
            - ./neodb/data/:/data/ 
            - ./neodb/conf/:/conf/
            - ./neodb/logs/:/logs/             
            - ./neodb/plugins/:/plugins/   
            - ./neodb/import/:/import/ 
        ports:
            - "27474:7474" 
            - "27687:7687"
        environment:
            - NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true 
            - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true 
            - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use_neo4j_config=true
            - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.*
            - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=512m
            - NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=2G
            - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test
        networks: ['Neo4j_lab']
        restart: unless-stopped

networks: {Neo4j_lab: {}}
# use docker volume to persist data outside of a container.
volumes:
  Neo4j_lab_data:
```

How can i keep the databases of two containers separately ?  I have kept these both `docker-compose.yml` files in two separate directories.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should map the port of your second Neo4j container to an other port for your host :

```
ports:
  - "27474:7474" 
  - "27687:7687"
```

Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports gor more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This does not solve the problem because when i create a new container with docker-compose, it still points to the database of existing database.

I need a new fresh container with its separate data.